# Prevent text from being animated in sonar effect animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

See my codepen: http://codepen.io/Chiz/pen/YypzYx

Hover over the grey square and the sonar effect animation comes out.
Everything is good, however, is there a way to prevent the text ("Click", in this case), from being animated along together with the sonar effect? I want the text to just stay there.

Here's the code for convenience:

```js
$(".square").on("mouseover", function() {
  $(this).children().first().addClass("square-inner");
});

$(".square").on("mouseleave", function() {
  $(this).children().first().removeClass("square-inner");
});
```

```css
/* Prevent scrollbars to appear when waves go out of bound */

.sonar-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.square {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
  margin: 5rem auto;
}
.square-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: HSL(45, 100%, 50%);
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events: none;
  animation: sonarWave 2s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes sonarWave {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(3);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
div {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sonar-wrapper">
  <div class="square">
    <div><a href="#">Click</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move `<a>` element outside div:

```
<div class="sonar-wrapper">
  <div class="square">
    <div></div>
    <a href="#">Click</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PPboea). In this case, anchor element will stay untransformed.